# Stacks with representable morphisms to algebraic stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks

If $Y$ is an algebraic stack over a scheme $S$ and  $X$ is a stack such that there exists an $S$-morphism $X\to Y$ representable by algebraic spaces, then is $X$ an algebraic stack (in the sense that its diagonal is representable, and that it admits a smooth presentation)?

My guess is that this is quite obvious (by simply pulling-back the smooth presentation and consideration of some Cartesian diagrams involving diagonals). I just wanted to be sure I'm not missing any subtleties.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see  http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05UM

(If I understand correctly, the "contained in $Sch_{fppf}$" condition just means that we must [work with schemes](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/021R) that have some upper bound on their cardinality to avoid set-theoretic difficulties.)

I think the argument that you are thinking of does indeed work (and is essentially the argument stacks project gives), but I would encourage you to write down the commutative diagrams yourself to see how it works out.

I also encourage you to search on Google, the stacks project, or in other sources to find a good reference, which is often all it takes.